# place holder and cursor positioning CSS

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using font-awesome icons in my HTML input text area. Once applied the CSS below place holder and cursor both are in different places want to make it at the same point. I am using CSS and HTML. I don't understand where I am going wrong.

```css
.inputIcons{
  position:relative
}

.inputIcons i{
  position:absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 8px;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  transition:.3s;
}

input::placeholder{
  padding-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall ">
   <div class="inputIcons">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value placeholder="Email " v-model="email" autocomplete="off" required 
      />
     <i class="fas fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using padding-left on the placeholder, apply on input and it will affect both the placeholder & cursor position.

```css
.inputIcons{
   position:relative;
}

.inputIcons i{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -7px;
    padding: 9px 8px;
    transition:.3s;
}

input{
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
  <div class="inputIcons">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value placeholder="Email " v-model="email" autocomplete="off" required 
              />
    <i class="fas fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this use top -7px to  .inputIcons i

```css
 .inputIcons{position:relative;}
   .inputIcons i{position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -7px;
    padding: 9px 8px;
    transition:.3s;
    }
    input::placeholder{
       padding-left: 35px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall ">
   <div class="inputIcons">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value placeholder="Email " v-model="email" autocomplete="off" required 
      />
       <i class="fas fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </div>
      </div> `
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need cursor and place holder in one place is that possible